# When passing data from View Model through javascript function, events are not triggered

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am using SambaPlayer API (Documentation -> http://dev.sambatech.com/documentation/player/api/metodos-e-eventos/) to incorporate a video in my page, but in order to do that I have to pass the video id via js, which I am getting from the controller via View Model. Here is my code:

```
var playerConfig = {
    height: 360,
    width: 640,
    ph: "df63f6e5bff216691764ae488e01427c",
    m: "@Model.Videos.First().IdVideo", //HERE IS WHERE IT GOES THE VIDEO ID
    events: {
        "*": "eventListener"
    },
    playerParams: {
        wideScreen: true
    }
};

var player = new SambaPlayer("player", playerConfig);
function eventListener(player) {
    alert(player.event);
}
```

The problem is: when I am passing my id like this, the video is loaded, but the events aren't triggering. Only the first one (onLoad) is, but I need to get other events like onFinish and onStart.
I've checked already the response, when alert "@Model.Videos.First().IdVideo", it prints correctly the id value. The only way I could made it work was to hard code the id.

---

#### Solved

*I've found out what caused this issue. For some reason when I was passing the video id through the view model it was adding blank spaces, which was imperceptible on the alert. So I just added .Trim() in the video id variable on controller and it worked. I don't know why this happened and why the video was loading anyway and just not triggering the events. Still, problem solved.*

Comment: Did you try just swaping eventListener function before intialization of player?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what caused this issue. For some reason when I was passing the video id through the view model it was adding blank spaces, which was imperceptible on the alert. So I just added .Trim() in the video id variable on controller and it worked. I don't know why this happened and why the video was loading anyway and just not triggering the events. Still, problem solved.